# Why is this tree search implementation causing a performance leak?

Tags: python, performance, search, tree

I'm coding a tree search in  a simultaneous move game in python. I'm using python at this stage for ease of development, before rewriting the project in C++. For this  reason,  I would normally not be too concerned about performance.  Originally my code was structured like this

```py
class DecisionNode():
    def __init__(self, players):
        self.transitions = dict()
        self.N = [dict() for _ in players]
        self.V = [dict() for _ in players]
        self.visited = 0
        self.c = 2
        self.players = players

    def search(self, s, depth=0, verbose=False, mode=None):
        if not self.visited: #unexpanded node
            score, log = s.rollout()
            actions = s.actions()
            for acts, n, v in zip(actions, self.N, self.V):
                for a in acts:
                    n[a] = 0
                    v[a] = 0
            for x in actions[0]:
                for y in actions[1]:
                    self.transitions[(x, y)] = TransitionNode(self.players)
            self.visited += 1
            return score, depth, False
        else:

            if not self.transitions: #terminal node
                score, log = s.rollout()
                return score, depth, True

            else: #recursive call

                actionTuple = self.selectActions(verbose, mode)
                transition = self.transitions[actionTuple]
                
                if not transition.step:
                    transition.expand(s.apply(actionTuple, battle.Path()))

                steps = transition.select()
                path, s_ = s.apply(actionTuple, battle.Path(steps))[0]
                child = transition.decisions[steps]

                score, d, terminal = child.search(s_, depth+1, verbose, mode)

                for _, a, n, v, in zip(score, actionTuple, self.N, self.V):
                    n[a] += 1
                    v[a] += _
                self.visited += 1
                return score, d, terminal

    def selectActions(self, verbose=False, mode=None):
        actionTuple = ()
        data = [[], []]
        for _ in self.players:
            actions = self.N[_].keys()
            for a in actions:
                n = self.N[_][a] + 1
                v = self.V[_][a]
                if mode is None:
                    score = v/n + self.c * math.sqrt(math.log(self.visited)/n)
                data[_].append((a, score))
            actionTuple += (max(data[_],key= lambda datum : datum[1])[0],)

        return actionTuple

class TransitionNode():
    def __init__(self, players):
        self.players = players
        self.step = []
        self.probs = []
        self.paths = []
        self.decisions = dict()
    def expand(self, batch):
        for path, state in batch:
            self.step.append(path.step)
            self.probs.append(path.p)
            self.paths.append(path)
            self.decisions[path.step] = DecisionNode(self.players)
    def select(self):
        steps = numpy.random.choice(self.paths, 1, p=self.probs)[0].step
        return steps
```

Essentially, there are two different nodes, one for the player's decisions and one for chance. Crucially, all the methods for the search are in the class. It's a recursive search; at each decision node each player selects a move according to the UCT formula, that node has a dictionary of action tuples and points to a chance node. That chance node has a dict of decision nodes it points to, and it randomly samples a decision node. This continues deeper down the tree, until it hits a terminal node or an unexpanded decision node, where it expands and returns the rollout value back up the tree to the root.

Now this code is python slow but not slow. I've been timing how long it takes to do bathes of 3000 root to leaf traversals like above,  and importantly it does not take any longer to do the tenth batch vs the first. You might expect it would take longer because of expansion of the tree, therefore deeper traversals. But in the case I gave it most of the traversals are hitting terminal nodes about 8 recursive calls in.

So why fix what's not broken? Well I noticed that my memory usage was exploding, probably because each node had its own copy of the methods attached. So, I rewrote the code so that both node classes only had statistics attached, and all the motion was provided by another Search class which contains all the methods. I  also changed the provably ineffective UCT algorithm to a regret matching one. This is going to be slower, since its a *bit* more involved:

```py
import numpy
import battle
import time

class Decision():
    def __init__(self):
        self.expanded = False

class Chance():
    def __init__(self):
        self.X = (0,0)
        self.n = 0

class Search():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def expandDecision(self, node, state):
        node.actions = state.actions()
        node.regrets = tuple([0 for a in _] for _ in node.actions)
        node.strategies = tuple([0 for a in _] for _ in node.actions)
        node.chances = dict()
        for _ in range(len(node.actions[0])):
            for __ in range(len(node.actions[1])):
                node.chances[(_, __)] = Chance()
        node.expanded = True

    def expandChance(self, chance, state, moves):
        chance.decisions = dict()
        batch = state.apply(moves)
        chance.steps = tuple(pair[0].step for pair in batch)
        chance.p = tuple(pair[0].p for pair in batch)

    def sampleChance(self, chance):
        step = chance.steps[numpy.random.choice(range(len(chance.steps)), 1, p=chance.p)[0]]
        if not step in chance.decisions.keys():
            chance.decisions[step] = Decision()
        return chance.decisions[step]

    def getStrategy(self, node):
        epsilon = 10**-3
        s = [[max(__, epsilon) for __ in _] for _ in node.regrets]
        t = [sum(_) for _ in s]
        s = [[___/__ for ___ in _] for _, __ in zip(s, t)]
        return s

    def avgScore(self, chance):
        return tuple((chance.X[_])/(chance.n + (chance.n == 0)) for _ in range(2))
    
    def getRegrets(self, node, actions, u):
        r = [[self.avgScore(node.chances[actions[:_] + (i,) + actions[_+1:]])[_] - u[_] for i in range(len(node.actions[_]))] for _ in range(2)]
        r[0][actions[0]] = 0
        r[1][actions[1]] = 0
        return r

    def sampleActions(self, strategy, gamma=0):
        uniform = tuple([1/len(_)]*len(_) for _ in strategy)
        fuzzy = tuple([(1-gamma)*x + (gamma)*y for x, y in zip(_, __)] for _, __ in zip(strategy, uniform))
        return tuple(numpy.random.choice(range(len(_)), 1, p=_)[0] for _ in fuzzy)

    def getMoves(self, node, actions):
        return tuple(_[i] for i, _ in zip(actions, node.actions))

    def updateDecision(self, node, r, s):
        for _ in range(2):
            for __ in range(len(node.actions[_])):
                node.regrets[_][__] += r[_][__]
                node.strategies[_][__] += s[_][__]

    def updateChance(self, chance, u):
        chance.X = tuple(chance.X[_] + u[_] for _ in range(2))
        chance.n += 1

    def averageStrategy(self, node):
        return tuple(tuple(__/s for __ in _) for _, s in zip(node.strategies, map(sum, node.strategies)))

    def search(self, node, state, gamma=0, depth=0):

        if not node.expanded:
            self.expandDecision(node, state)
            return state.rollout()[0], depth, False
        
        if not any(node.actions):
            return state.rollout()[0], depth, True
        
        sigma = self.getStrategy(node)
        actions = self.sampleActions(sigma, gamma)
        moves = self.getMoves(node, actions)

        chance = node.chances[actions]
        if not chance.n:
            self.expandChance(chance, state, moves)

        node_ = self.sampleChance(chance)

        u, _, terminal = self.search(node_, state.apply(moves)[0][1], gamma, depth+1)

        regrets = self.getRegrets(node, actions, u)

        self.updateDecision(node, regrets, sigma)
        self.updateChance(chance, u)
        return self.avgScore(chance), _, terminal

if __name__ == '__main__':

    node = Decision()
    state = battle.s

    __ = 3000
    test = Search()

    a = time.time()
    total_depth = 0
    terminal_count = 0
    for _ in range(__ * 10):
        test = Search()
        u, depth, terminal = test.search(node, state, gamma=.03)
        total_depth += depth
        terminal_count += terminal

        if (_+1)%__ == 0:
            
            print(_+1)
            for action, chance in node.chances.items():
                print(node.actions)
                print(action, chance.n, test.avgScore(chance))

            print(test.averageStrategy(node))

            #depth
            avg_depth = total_depth/__
            terminal_ratio = terminal_count/__
            print('avg_depth: ', avg_depth)
            print('terminal: ', terminal_ratio)
            total_depth = 0
            terminal_count = 0

            #time
            b = time.time()
            print('t= ', b - a)
            a = b
```

However this implementation is **much** slower. rather that a constant time (~20 sec) per batch, I have times of 20, 60, 100, 140 etc. Each batch of 3000 simulations is taking 40 seconds slower than the last!

I actually wrote a control case that uses the detached search of the later code and the UCT of the former and this still exhibits the slowdown effect. I thought maybe it was because I was reusing the same search object for all calls so I tried periodically re-instantiating it but to no avail.

Comment: it is always worth profiling your code when you are not sure why it was slow / fast: https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/ Also it is a good idea to profile before "optimizing"

Comment: Thank you taylor. I tried profiling and it allowed me to discover that the performance issue was stemming from extra recursive calls in my other module... so essentially I was using my own code wrong!

Comment: glad to help! feel free to explain your solution as an answer to this post. Will help anyone else with similar problems